# How can I use Hedera JS SDK to generate a set of ECDSA key-pairs based on a BIP-39 seed phrase and a custom derivation path?

Tags: javascript, ecdsa, mnemonics, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I'm currently using the Hedera JS SDK to generate a single ECDSA key-pair using a private key directly as an input, like so:

```js
const privateKey = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA(process.env.TARGET_HEX_PRIVATE_KEY);
```

Instead I would like to do something like this instead, where I am using a BIP-39 seed phrase and a derivation path as inputs:

```js
const mnemonic = Mnemonic.fromString(process.env.TARGET_SEED_PHRASE);
const privateKey = await mnemonic.toEcdsaPrivateKey('', "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0");
```

However, [`Mnemonic`'s `toEcdsaPrivateKey` function](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/v2.24.0/src/Mnemonic.js#L109-L121) seems to accept an array of numbers as the input for the derivation path, based on its JsDoc `@param` comment, copied below:

```js
    /**
     * Recover an ECDSA private key from this mnemonic phrase, with an
     * optional passphrase.
     *
     * @param {string} [passphrase]
     * @param {number[]} [path]
     * @returns {Promise<PrivateKey>}
     */
    async toEcdsaPrivateKey(passphrase = "", path) {
        return CACHE.privateKeyConstructor(
            await this._mnemonic.toEcdsaPrivateKey(passphrase, path)
        );
    }
```

In my use case, I would like to work with MetaMask, which unfortunately does not yet support custom derivation paths per network configuration, and hardcodes the Ethereum derivation path of `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0` instead. Note that the first 3 segments are "hardened", while the remaining 2 are not.

How can I specify this derivation path?

Comment: There are some examples in the documentation, e.g. [here](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/1a73f3f1329a48702f2a5170260bd05f186e0ca3/packages/cryptography/src/Mnemonic.js#L35) or [here](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/e0cd39c84ab189d59a6bcedcf16e4102d7bb8beb/packages/cryptography/test/unit/Mnemonic.js#L61).

Comment: Ah thanks @Topaco - the binary OR with `0x80000000` looks like what I'm after!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest release, v2.24.1,
the `Mnemonic` class has been updated to deprecate
[`toEcdsaPrivateKey`](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js/blob/v2.24.1/src/Mnemonic.js#L124-L137):

```js
    /**
     * @deprecated - Use `toStandardEd25519PrivateKey()` or `toStandardECDSAsecp256k1PrivateKey()` instead
     * Recover an ECDSA private key from this mnemonic phrase, with an
     * optional passphrase.
     * @param {string} [passphrase]
     * @param {number[]} [path]
     * @returns {Promise<PrivateKey>}
     */
```

... so using the methods suggested by @Topaco in the comments,
where each hardened segment is binary `OR`-ed with `0x80000000`,
is not going to work.
... and therefore **not possible** to achieve my intended outcome
using only Hedera JS SDK.

So here's a **workaround** that uses EthersJs in combination
with the Hedera JS SDK to achieve the intended outcome:

```js
import { PrivateKey } from "@hashgraph/sdk";
import { utils as ethersUtils } from "ethers";

// init a hierarchically deterministic wallet's node using a seed phrase
const hdNodeRoot = ethersUtils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(process.env.TARGET_SEED_PHRASE);

// apply the derivation path, `accountIdx` starts at `0`
const hdNodeX = hdNodeRoot.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/${accountIdx}`);

// convert from ethersjs private key to hedera js sdk private key
const privateKeyX = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA(hdNodeX.privateKey);

// extract the `0x...` address from the private key
const addressX = privateKeyX.publicKey.toEvmAddress();
```

The significant bit is where `utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic` from EthersJs
is used in place of `Mnemonic.toEcdsaPrivateKey` from Hedera JS SDK.

---

Here's [a more complete example](https://gist.github.com/bguiz/be2d9eaf2239600b5760fc991bb8c879),
where I create multiple accounts using the above method,
and fund them from an ED22519 account
(originally generated on and funded by the [Hedera Testnet Portal](https://portal.hedera.com/),
which sort of functions like a faucet).

Comment: adding the checkmark to this answer... but if anyone finds a way to do this without this workaround - i.e. using the Hedera JS SDK only - will be happy to switch the checkmark over to the newer answer!